# custom li selectbox cannot select when using iscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I am using the iscroll.js in my project and also i have using the custom select box in a page. But if i use isroll and custom select box in a page the selectbox cannot select.

Here is my html code

```
<div id="expiration" class="monthSelect selectbox">
                                <input type="text" id="month" readonly="readonly" value="MM" name="">

                                <div id="dropListmnth" class="dropList" style="display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                    <ul>  
                                        <li value="1">1-Jan</li>  
                                        <li value="2">2-Feb</li>
                                        <li value="3">3-Mar</li>
                                        <li value="4">4-Apr</li>
                                        <li value="5">5-May</li>
                                        <li value="6">6-Jun</li>
                                        <li value="7">7-July</li>
                                        <li value="8">8-Aug</li>
                                        <li value="9">9-Sept</li>
                                        <li value="10">10-Oct</li>
                                        <li value="11">11-Nov</li>
                                        <li value="12">12-Dec</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

When i click the selectbox the ul>li will come in the dropdown it working correctly, but i cannot able to select the value from the dropdown li. Anybody have any idea about the issue?

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: DO i need to paste the code there?